# How to disable IPv6 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, networking, ipv6

I disabled IPv6 on an Ubuntu box which has ssh and rsync running. But both of these are still listening on an IPv6 address. How should I fix this?

```
root@box.com:~# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
root@box.com:~# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
root@box.com:~# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And

```
root@box.com:~# ss -lnp6
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128            :::22                 :::*      users:(("sshd",1505,4))
LISTEN     0      5              :::873                :::*      users:(("rsync",3423,5))
```

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41543/how-to-dynamically-enable-and-disable-ipv6-on-an-interface?rq=1

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's very unlikely that disabling IPv6 will solve it.

Comment: We do not use ipv6 (yet). So just trying to reduce security risk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable IPv6 in Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I would say the duplicate possibility is reversed since this question predates that one.

Comment: But still, if you don't have any routing IPv6 in your LAN, it will be no security risk.  Just some unneeded configuration.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This worked for me:

Add these lines to the bottom of sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then run `sudo sysctl -p` or reboot

source:  http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/disable-ipv6-if-your-internet-is.html

This of course won't stop bind from blindly trying to use ipv6 though, so you also need to alter `/etc/default/bind9` like so:

```
# run resolvconf? 
RESOLVCONF=yes 
# startup options for the server 
OPTIONS="-4 -u bind"
```

source: http://blog.evilcoder.net/disable-ipv6-on-bind9-linux/#sthash.U95y4s6U.dpuf

Comment: Warning - don't click the link above. there is a virus or somethig

Comment: There are 2 links above, can you be more specific?

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated, just blacklist the  `ipv6` module.

Answer (score 22):

To check if IPv6 is enabled or disabled, from a terminal window:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

0 means it’s enabled and 1 is disabled.

To disable IPv6

```
$ sudo su -
# nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and add these lines to sysctl.conf file

```
#disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Save sysctl.conf file with new config, then reboot your system

```
# reboot
```

Check your system again

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

Now you should see “1″ means IPv6 has been disabled on your system.

From http://namhuy.net/1419/disable-ipv6-ubuntu-linux-mint.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a terminal and type the following command (if you don't use Gedit, replace it with your text editor such as Kate, etc).

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. And search for this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
   ```

   Modify it so it looks like this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
   ```
3. Now, let's update the GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub2
   ```

   Or if you don't use GRUB 2, do:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. And finally, restart your system.

Comment: I know that should work, but did not seem to solve my problem! `netstat -nutlp | grep ::` shows that sshd and ntpd are listening on ipv6 addresses.

Comment: Just remove the module `ipv6`, and you are done. Why you ever wanted to do this...

Comment: It's not a separate module that can blacklisted, it's builtin. You cannot remove the ipv6 module.

Answer (score 0):

**Disable listening on ipv6 addresses for some services.**

sshd /etc/default/ssh

```
# Options to pass to sshd
SSHD_OPTS="-4"
```

avahi-daemon /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf

```
[server]
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=no
```

java /etc/java-7-openjdk/net.properties

```
http.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*
ftp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*
```

Then restart services

```
service restart sshd
service restart avahi-daemon
service restart tomcat7
```

In my case tomcat was using java with ipv6. May differ for you.

Answer (score 0):

To just turn of IPv6 on your computer, why you ever wanted to do that, is easy.  Just add one line to a configuration file. Yes, you have to be `root` to create the file.

```
$ cat <<EOF >/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ipv6.conf
# To turn off IPv6, though you don't need too.
# But anyways.
blacklist ipv6

# eof
EOF
```

Just reboot or try:

```
$ sudo rmmod ipv6
```