# Disable ipv6 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I found that post [How to disable IPv6 on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346126/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu)

I need to ask about this file `/etc/default/bind9`. I couldn't find this file.

Where can i find it?

Comment: You only need to change the bind config if you have bind installed, which for most common users is not the case.

Comment: this is the real problem , can you help on this http://serverfault.com/questions/747533/how-can-it-bind-port-with-ip-address-not-0-0-0-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind is related to DNS configuration to see **bind9** file in the path /etc/default/bind9

Run below command:

```
sudo apt-get install bind9
```

You can go through the link for exact steps:
[How to disable IPv6 in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: can you help in this http://serverfault.com/questions/747533/how-can-it-bind-port-with-ip-address-not-0-0-0-0

Comment: If you don't want to use `bind`, why install it?