# Problem with sudo apt-get update on Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine

Tags: apt, updates, virtualbox, csh

My problem began when I was tried to install the mmtsb (multiscale modelling toolset for structural biology) on an Ubuntu 14.04 Virtual Machine on a Windows Host.

I tried giving the ./install.sh command. But this was the error which propped up:

```
bash: ./install.sh: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

To resolve this I tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install csh
```

This in turn gave the following error:

```
Unable to locate package csh
```

I tried next to update the packages using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This in turn gave my the following error:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                 
Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What do I do now ?

Comment: For me it looks like you don't have a working network  configuration and therefor can't access the internet, which prevents apt from working as it cant access its servers (looks like IPv6 to me). Please ensure you have internet access in the first place, then run 'apt update && apt upgrade' and then continue by installing 'csh'

Comment: I do have a working internet access. How do I check if I have a working network configuration? I tried running apt apt update && apt upgrade. The errors which keep showing are: Cannot initiate the connection to extras.ubuntu.com:80  - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

Comment: Maybe it is really related with IPv4 vs IPv6. You could try running a normal ping from terminal (ping google.com) and then an IPv6 ping (ping6 google.com). If v4 works and v6 doesnt, try disabling ipv6 temporary via boot parameter or similar

Comment: ping google.com works. ping6 google.com does not work. The output of the latter is connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: My guess would be apt is trying to communicate whyever via IPv6, which seems not to work on your machine so far. A simple workaround would be to disable IPv6 (http://askubuntu.com/questions/346126/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu#381623) and then try to rerun your above apt commands

Comment: It has been 4 minutes since I gave the ping google.com command. It still has not finished execution. I'm completely new to Ubuntu and Computer Science as a whole. So I will need a step-by-step approach to resolve this problem. Also I'm using a proxy connection to the internet. Would that be the reason for this?

Comment: The above ping commands runs until you finish it via CTRL+C. Regarding proxy - this could be relevant, but i doubt it if your ipv4 ping works and surfing via port80 works as well. Try disabling ipv6 as mentioned before and report back

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand your problem but you may try this. By this may be you able to install packages using apt-get.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316812/ubuntu-apt-get-unable-to-fetch-packages/35096935#35096935

Comment: Thank you! When I gave this command: sudo do-release-upgrade
This was the output: No new release found

Comment: and you used sudo apt-get update after that ?

Comment: Yes. It looks like a network connection problem.                                                                                                                                           This along with other errors are shown: Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                             
  Cannot initiate the connection to extras.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)