# Disable IPv6 on 14.04 with IPv6 disabled kernel

Tags: 14.04, networking, kernel, ipv6

How do i disable system wide IPv6 within ubuntu?

I know so many answers in here about this but situation is different. This is an embedded device.

Here is my conditions:

- IPv6 disabled in kernel to gain some space
- Bootloader is u-boot

According to here >> [How to dynamically enable and disable ipv6 on an interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41543/how-to-dynamically-enable-and-disable-ipv6-on-an-interface) here is what i tried:

1. *net.ipv6.conf.** was not worked in *sysctl.conf*  because there is no
   */proc/sys/net/ipv6/* folder
2. Could not configure from grub because there is no grub (:

Digging within google gave me the same solutions. And still IPv6 couses problems with my wireless.

Any idea how to do?

Comment: Can you run sysctl -a | grep ipv6, to check any ipv6 related settings, please?

Comment: But anyway - if you want it disabled completely during the boot time in kernel - u-boot also seems to allow passing some kernel arguments, but quite honestly, I'm not very familiar with it to give a straight answer right now.

Comment: Sorry for late response. There is  nothing about ipv 6 in sysctl output. Isn't there must ve sth about ipv6 disabled? Yes i checked  u-boot parameters in forums but everyone says the same solution "there must be a parameter" (: But i think there is not, or i cant found at least.

Comment: Sorry about typo . It must be  " Isn't there must be something about ipv6 disabled?"

Comment: if sysctl doesn't show ipv6 entries, the good thing is it's already disabled - so related modules and ipv6 stack doesn't load. As for u-boot configuration - you will unfortunately have to dig it yourself, unless someone else here knows the ready answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: But there is an interesting thing. If i compile kernel with ipv6 support and arrange sysctl.conf to disable ipv6, it works (:

Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Well - if you compile your kernel with ipv6 support, yes, you'll see the entries with sysctl and then you can disable support this way. Otherwise there's nothing to disable - as ipv6 stack isn't present in the system then.

Comment: The problem starts in here . I need this IPv6's space to include things more necesarry into kernel. Because it will run in EPROM and has a very limited space.

Answer (score -1):

I think that if you worry about the little space that the IPv6 kernel module takes then you should probably be compiling your own kernel...

Comment: Yes i am compiling my own kernel but which part of the post  is answer i cant  understand sorry.

Comment: If you really compile your own kernel without ipv6 you most likely don't have to use boot loaded to disable it (you can't disable something that's not there). Unless you're confused about compiling your own kernel. But anyway - unless you're really very limited with disk/memory space - just basically disable modules, you don't need - modular construction of kernel helps in this kind of situations.

Comment: i got 1.9M size about kernel , and 0.5 M for modules to fit them in EPROM.  So i need to keep IPv6 to the out of the game. Because it is large and i could use this space for something more necessary.  So yes i really need this space.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I found was to edit `/etc/default/grub` with sudo powers and change the kernel command line with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 quiet splash"
```

Then save the file, followed by the customary:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: İ guess you missed Bootloader is u-boot part