# How to connect to ipv6?

Tags: networking, ipv6, dhcpv6

My server is connected to a network which supports ipv6, however, it can't connect to any ipv6 address. Ping6 returns a message "network is unreachable." and curl ipv6 don't work as well.
How to check whether my network really supports ipv6 and if so, how to let my server connect to it?

My server's dhcp.conf:https://termbin.com/3gjh
Linux 5.0.0-27-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 20 19:53:07 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: YOur network may support IPv6, but has it assigned an IPv6 **address** to your computer that is not link-local?  If not you have to set one up and configure it.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes. My network address are auto assigned by a dhcp server. How to ask it assign an ipv6  address for me?

Comment: You said this is a server, how do you have your DHCP configured?  Which Ubuntu version is this?  Are you using Netplan to manage your server's network configuration?

Comment: Is IPv6 enabled on your computer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/41543/how-to-dynamically-enable-and-disable-ipv6-on-an-interface

Comment: @ThomasWard my question is updated.

Comment: @StephenBoston It seems that it is not where the question lays.