# how do i enable ipv6 on ubuntu 18.04 lts and nginx ipv6?

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, ipv6

when i run `ifconfig` i get the following

`$ ifconfig`

```
...
...
...
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a6:16:08:e6:c5:15
          inet addr:191.168.1.59  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1416:3ff:fee6:c515/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37382 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3435 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1804996 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:810638 (810.6 KB)
...
...
...
```

the ipv6 it is showing is `Scope:Link` but i don't see the `Scope:Global` one which i see in online tutorials.

How do i get that second ipv6 address that i can route to?

Here is what my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like

`$ cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

the whole reason for this is to be able to reach my nginx server by both ipv4 and ipv6
Right now i can reach it by the **private ipv4 address** `http:192.168.1.59`
but i also want to be able to reach it via the **private ipv6 address** as well
can anyone please explain to me how to enable this ipv6?

Here is what my sysctl settings looks like for all ipv6 settings

`$ sysctl -a | grep ipv6`

```
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.anycast_src_echo_reply = 0
net.ipv6.auto_flowlabels = 1
net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.force_tllao = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.all.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.all.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.mldv1_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv6.conf.all.mldv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv6.conf.all.mtu = 1280
net.ipv6.conf.all.ndisc_notify = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.regen_max_retry = 3
net.ipv6.conf.all.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitations = 3
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.all.suppress_frag_ndisc = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.all.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_oif_addrs_only = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.force_tllao = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.default.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.default.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.mldv1_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv6.conf.default.mldv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv6.conf.default.mtu = 1280
net.ipv6.conf.default.ndisc_notify = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.regen_max_retry = 3
net.ipv6.conf.default.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.default.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.default.router_solicitations = 3
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.docker0.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.default.suppress_frag_ndisc = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.default.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_oif_addrs_only = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.force_tllao = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.mldv1_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.mldv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.mtu = 1500
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.ndisc_notify = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.regen_max_retry = 3
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.router_solicitations = 3
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eth0.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.suppress_frag_ndisc = 1
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.use_oif_addrs_only = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.force_tllao = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mldv1_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mldv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mtu = 1500
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.ndisc_notify = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.regen_max_retry = 3
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_solicitations = 3
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.suppress_frag_ndisc = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_oif_addrs_only = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_dad = -1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.force_tllao = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.lo.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.lo.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mldv1_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mldv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mtu = 65536
net.ipv6.conf.lo.ndisc_notify = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.regen_max_retry = 3
net.ipv6.conf.lo.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.lo.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.lo.router_solicitations = 3
net.ipv6.conf.lo.suppress_frag_ndisc = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.lo.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.lo.use_oif_addrs_only = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.use_tempaddr = -1
net.ipv6.flowlabel_consistency = 1
net.ipv6.flowlabel_state_ranges = 0
net.ipv6.fwmark_reflect = 0
net.ipv6.icmp.ratelimit = 1000
net.ipv6.idgen_delay = 1
net.ipv6.idgen_retries = 3
net.ipv6.ip6frag_high_thresh = 262144
net.ipv6.ip6frag_low_thresh = 196608
net.ipv6.ip6frag_secret_interval = 0
net.ipv6.ip6frag_time = 60
net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind = 0
net.ipv6.mld_max_msf = 64
net.ipv6.mld_qrv = 2
net.ipv6.neigh.default.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv6.neigh.default.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 128
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 512
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 1024
net.ipv6.neigh.default.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.default.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv6.neigh.default.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.default.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.default.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv6.neigh.default.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv6.route.gc_elasticity = 9
net.ipv6.route.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv6.route.gc_min_interval = 0
net.ipv6.route.gc_min_interval_ms = 500
net.ipv6.route.gc_thresh = 1024
net.ipv6.route.gc_timeout = 60
net.ipv6.route.max_size = 4096
net.ipv6.route.min_adv_mss = 1220
net.ipv6.route.mtu_expires = 600
net.ipv6.xfrm6_gc_thresh = 2147483647
```

what do i need to do to get this ipv6 working on ubuntu 18.04?

thanks

UPDATE(S):

output of `ip addr`

`$ ip addr`

```
...
...
...
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a6:16:08:e6:c5:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.59/16 brd 10.247.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a416:8ff:fee6:c515/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
...
...
```

Comment: i get same thing...will update my question to show output..so check the update

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41543/how-to-dynamically-enable-and-disable-ipv6-on-an-interface

Comment: Unless you've explicitly configured against it, 18.04 network configuration is through netplan.

Comment: @StephenBoston do you understand what i want? i want to be able to reach the private ipv6 address same way i can reach the nginx via the private ipv4 address...got it?

Comment: Hmmm. There's no setting in Ubuntu that needs to be turned on -- IPv6 works on Ubuntu out-of-the-box. I wonder if your router (or ISP) may not be properly configured for IPv6. On my Ubuntu systems that use IPv6, the entire routable address shows. The only time that the entire routable address did not show was due to a router misconfiguration.  (troubleshooting that was a not-fun day)

Comment: I have a server on my LAN. When I'm away from home, I can access that server via its IPv6 address.  Like that?